# sailsjs override session&connections adapters with sails.lift

Tags: mocha.js, sails.js

I am writing Unit Tests for my SailsJS and suddenly the Database was removed.

I want to be able to do something like this in my unit tests files:

```
sails.lift({ 
    session_adapter: { secret: '137eafklajeaf', adapter: 'mongo', host: 'localhost', ...},
    connection_adapter: { adapter: 'sails-mongo', host: 'localhost', ...},
    log: { level: 'verbose' }
});
```

- Is it the good practice to test your app?
- How do I achieve this?
- Where I can find the documentation of sails lift and other functions?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the good practice to test your app?

In general, yes.

> How do I achieve this?

https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example. And I guess this is what you'd like to do: https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example/blob/master/test/index.js#L9

> Where I can find the documentation of sails lift and other functions?

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs. Reading [the source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) is even better.

Comment: what about the session adapter? how do I pass this to sails lift function?

Comment: @user2867106 Passing the adapter you want to use as a `session` property of configuration object (which is a parameter to `Sails.lift`) should work.